# How to calculate the time derivative of electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, speed

How can I calculate the time derivative of an electric field from its space derivative? That is, I know $\frac{dV}{dx}$, and I need $\frac{dV}{dt}$. In general, $\frac{dV}{dt}$ = $\frac{dV}{dx} \times \frac{dx}{dt}$. However, $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is the speed of the propagation of the field. According to Newton, it is infinitely large. At the same time, since the time is absolute, the electric field does not depend on time.

Comment: What is $x$ here exactly? The position of what? For example, it could be the position of a charged particle whose motion you're trying to simulate. But "dx/dt is the speed of the propagation of the field. According to Newton, it is infinitely large" doesn't make any sense to me. First off Newton made no statements about electric field. The existence of an electric field was not known to Newton. Second, electric field is not a fluid. You cannot track its motion. You could, arbitrarily, consider a point in space that moves at the speed of light, but why?

Comment: Instead, you need to rearrange the [Ampère–Maxwell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law#Extending_the_original_law:_the_Amp%C3%A8re%E2%80%93Maxwell_equation) as $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{E}=c^2(\nabla\times\vec{B}-\mu_0\vec{J})$.

Comment: @AXensen Well, Newton assumed absolute time and that means instant interaction. That is infinitely  large speed of propagation. Newton spoke about forces, and that is what an electric charge in the space feels. Yes, you can track the motion of electromagnetic field: the light from the Sun to Earth  travels  8-10 minutes.This is what classic physics cannot consider.

Comment: @ J.G. My question was a thought experiment. If you create a charge Q1 and have a distant Q2 somewhere, it will feel the electric field with some delay. In the classic physics, there is no delay. (In my question: there is no convection)

Comment: @katang you are looking for the concept of 'retarded time'

Comment: @jensen paull I quess, you are the on the right track. Actually, I am attempting to solve an electrodiffusion problem. However, in my eyes, it is not retarded time, it is a finite speed of interaction, such as EM field. The Minkowski-math describes the problem. The classic physics uses infinitely high propagation speed; and I am at the boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the problem is posed, this is impossible. just knowing the spacial variation  of an electric field  at a specific moment in time does not mean you have any knowledge of its time variance. I assume you mean $\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial x}$ and not the total derivative. If you did mean the total derivative and you want to find the time variance of the electric field experienced by an object moving with some velocity function you could use the convective derivative $$\frac{D\vec{E}}{Dt} = (\vec{V} \cdot \nabla )\vec{E} +\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t} $$ Where  the partial derivative should be 0 to be solvable or atleast known.

Theoretically although not what I suspect you are asking, is that if we are given specific functions that represent the partial derivatives of the electric field, that are valid for all moments in time(and thus most likely time dependant), we could construct the divergence and curl and solve the equations for E and then take its partial derivative